# How to protect app hosted on Google Cloud Run?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm looking into building a Cloud Run based API that requires authentication. Is it possible to invoke it only if the request meets some security checks for example:

- Query string passes my function (eg. param X has value of Y)

or

- Authorization header value passes my function (JWT verification)

I'm afraid that if I run those checks after invocation, someone can DDoS my API and I will be the one to pay the bill.

Comment: Unless you enable IAM authorization, anyone can invoke your Cloud Run service. https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/overview If you enable IAM authorization, your service is not invoked if authorization fails (your service is protected).

Comment: @JohnHanley Isn't the IAM authorization intended just for Google Sign-In? I couldn't find any information regarding authenticating my external identity.

Comment: If you are using an external identity, then you are not using Google IAM authorization. That means the protection that Google provides does not apply. If you are concerned with DDoS, then you will need to adopt Google's authorization strategies and methods. Note: Google now offers `Workload Identity Federation` which supports some external identity providers to exchange external creditials for IAM credentials. There are many options available, some are complex to implement and have their own additional costs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use IAM authentication and require a valid and authorized authentication to access the service. You have example [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/overview). All the not authorized traffic is filter by Google (Google Front end (or GFE) layer)

You can also deploy an API Gateway (or a Cloud Endpoint, the feature are very similar) and accept an API key. It's not recommended but in some situation it's better than nothing. I [wrote an article on that](https://medium.com/google-cloud/secure-cloud-run-cloud-functions-and-app-engine-with-api-key-73c57bededd1). You will pay the number of requests on API Gateway (good or not), but your service is protected and the valid requests processed.

You can also try a new feature for [Cloud Run: IAP (Identity Aware Proxy)](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/cloud-run-sign-in). You need to deploy a Load Balancer and to plug IAP on it. With a Load balancer you can also deploy [Cloud Armor](https://cloud.google.com/armor) on it (a WAF) and then prevent your service against attacks.

Comment: So I read about IAM authentication but I'm not sure if I understand it correctly. I don't want to authenticate using Google sign-in, generate additional tokens or API keys. 

I already have a key, which is generated dynamically, outside Google platform, based on time and the user. It is valid just for few seconds.

On the Google Cloud side I just need to verify it. Is the IAM authentication the right direction?

Comment: No, if you have custom authentication mechanism, you need to use your own system, and thus to deal with issues and attacks yourselves. You can use a Load Balancer to use Cloud Armor to filter so IPs and OWASP malicious attacks, but nothing more. Either you comply with Google security mechanism, or do it on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ESPv2 https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-run#migrating_to.
You can add API key as well as JWT auth easily with firebase.

Comment: As written in the following official documentation article. The API keys can only belong to a project, not a user. So if you need to apply quotas based on who call the service it's not possible with Cloud Endpoint and API keys.

https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/restricting-api-access-with-api-keys#sharing_apis_protected_by_api_key